# Xamarin.Forms display a data in list works in debug but not in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a code which display a data in xamarin form as a list. It display well in debug mode but display nothing is list while in release or by APK. It release mode display display button in list which is a static only. 
Below is the code i have done in my form. can any once guide me to solve this.

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listLogin" ItemsSource="{Binding callLogList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid x:Name="Item">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ImgCallType" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Style="{Binding width:50px,height:50px;}"></Image>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" FontSize="Subtitle" Text="{Binding Mobilenumber}"></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Subtitle" Text="12345"></Label>
                            <Button  Grid.Column="4"  Text="Add"  TextColor="Black"   HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="" CommandParameter="{Binding Mobilenumber}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>

public partial class MiscallData : ContentPage
    {
        public MiscallData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetCallLogs();
        }
        public void GetCallLogs()
        {
            Android.Content.Context myContext = Android.App.Application.Context;

            string OutgoingqueryFilter = string.Format("{0}={1}", CallLog.Calls.Type, (int)CallType.Outgoing);
            string querySorter = string.Format("{0} desc ", CallLog.Calls.Date);

            ICursor OutgoingqueryData = myContext.ContentResolver.Query(CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null, null, null, querySorter);
            List<MisscallDataModel> callLogList = new List<MisscallDataModel>();

            while (OutgoingqueryData.MoveToNext())
            {
                MisscallDataModel model = new MisscallDataModel();

                //---phone number---
                model.Mobilenumber = OutgoingqueryData.GetString(OutgoingqueryData.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Number));

                //---date of call---
                int secondindex = OutgoingqueryData.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Date);
                long seconds = OutgoingqueryData.GetLong(secondindex);
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
                String dateString = formatter.Format(new Date(seconds));
                model.Date = dateString;
                model.ImageUrl = "BlockCall.png";
                callLogList.Add(model);
            }
            listLogin.ItemsSource = callLogList;
        }
    }

public class MisscallDataModel
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string Mobilenumber { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string callType { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are setting permission to read call logs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my que by my self, it is nothing wrong in code, it's just set in property setting, 
just go to android property and then select android option , just find Linker property there is linking , select option None, that's it.

Android project => Property => Android Options => Linker Properties => Linking => None.

Comment: These all about of release mode. Finally you find this answer. great work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Same problem for me with binding between other type of elements.

Comment: NOTE:  I aloso had to delete all OBJ & BIN files in PCL and Android projets to force a complete rebuild of the solution !

Comment: what is the solution for MAUI?